# How do I Insert Latitude/Longtitude in my database & use it to open Google maps with Intent?

Tags: android, sql, latitude-longitude

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    firstName VARCHAR(50),
    lastName VARCHAR(50),
    title VARCHAR(50),
    department VARCHAR(50),
    managerId INTEGER,
    city VARCHAR(50),
    officePhone VARCHAR(30),
    cellPhone VARCHAR(30),
    email VARCHAR(30),
    picture VARCHAR(200))
INSERT INTO employee VALUES(1,'Ryan','Howard','Vice President, North East',
    'Management', NULL, 'Scranton','570-999-8888',
    '570-999-8887','ryan@dundermifflin.com','howard.jpg')
```

Comment: What is the specific question? Is there a problem with formulating the INSERT query? Do you have problems with the location API? Please specify.

Answer (score 3):

You really should put more time into formulating your question. I'm unsure what exactly you're stuck on. I'd recommend starting from scratch. Look at location + Android and how they tie together.
[Here](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/01/android-location-api/) is an example of an app that works with location services.

There is a similar question to yours answered well [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android). If it is SQLite that's giving you issues have a look at [this](http://www.google.ie/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=5&sqi=2&ved=0CD8QFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.screaming-penguin.com%2Fnode%2F7742&ei=imleTZXKIcuXhQek5tiFDg&usg=AFQjCNGzNWYJbfBR6ZQHGAIXSzyPsNO_QA). Due to the lack of information I'm unsure what it is you're asking specifically.  Hopefully these few suggestions will answer your query. If not add more information and I will attempt to give you a more specific answer.

Comment: Sorry if my question didn't make much sense my English is not first language. Ok, Lets say I've a column call 'Location' in my table above and in it I've Lat/Lon coordinates stored in the first Field (rest NULL) then I want to use that lat/lon stored in that Field to open google maps is there a way to do it?